# How $0 is used in awk, how it works?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
read n
awk '
    BEGIN {sum=0;}{if( $0%2==0 ){sum+=$0;
     }
     }
     END { print sum}'
```

Here i add, `sum of even numbers` and what i want is, initially i give input as how many(count) and then the numbers i wanted to check as even and add it.

`eg)
3
6
7
8
output is : 14`

here `3 is count` and followed by `numbers i want to check`, the code is executed correctly and output is correct, but i wanted to know how `$0 left the count value i.e) 3`  and calculates the remaining numbers.

Comment: `$0` is an awk variable, it has nothing to do with unix; most shells use `$0` for something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your question to be meaningful: There is no relationship between `$0` and the Unix operating system, as choroba already pointed out in his comment. You obviously want to know the meaning of $0 in the awk programming language. From the **awk man-page** in the section about **Fields**:

*$0 is the whole record, including leading and trailing  whitespace.*

Answer (score 1):

you're reading the count but not using it in the script,
a rewrite can be

```
$ awk 'NR==1  {n=$1; next}             // read the first value and skip the rest
      !($1%2) {sum+=$1}                // add up even numbers
       NR>n   {print sum; exit}' file  // done when the # linespass the counter.
```

in `awk`, `$0` corresponds to the record (here the line), and `$i` for the fields i=1,2,3...
even number is the one with remainder 0 divided by 2.  `NR` is the line number.